# Answered: using a pandas data frame and it is returning NaN, but when I print the value it is fine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas for  the first time, and in the data frame there is a piece of data that is a percentage as a string but  when put into a dataframe and printed it shows up as NaN. So to test it i just used a print statement  and it returns the value fine. Thank you!

```
def makeSheet():
  data = [schoolName, location, aceptanceRate, tuition, roomAndBoard, debtAtGrad, studentToTeacher, satReq, totalUndergrad]
  dataDictonary = {"School Name": schoolName, "Location": location, "Aceptance Rate": aceptanceRate, "Tuition": tuition, "Room & Board": roomAndBoard, "Estimated Debt at Grad": debtAtGrad, "Student:Teacher": studentToTeacher,
                   "SAT Req": satReq, "Total Number of Undergrads": totalUndergrad}
  df = pd.DataFrame(dataDictonary, columns=headers, index=[0])
  print(df)
  print(aceptanceRate)
```

the pandas data table returned:
[pandas data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPg80.png)

The print  statement returned:
31%

Answer:
I had to ensure the spelling was the same across both acceptance rates. As in the dataDictonary one had to match the headers one. Thank you to [Ignatius Reilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032126/ignatius-reilly) for the help

Comment: It would help if you can post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391).

Comment: The picture you shown has a column called `Acceptance Rate`, however, the code you used to create the df has a column called `Aceptance Rate` (with one 'c').

Comment: From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) about setting `columns` to a value not None: _If data contains column labels, will perform column selection_. So, it's selecting only the keys from `dataDictonary` that are called the same as the names from  `headers`.

Comment: Ah, thank you all! It works I had to change the naming of the title to match the variable.